# How do I retrieve the "Audio in" from the api (For example, stereo 2.0, Dolby Digital Plus 5.1)

Tags: sonos

I'm looking to get some information from the Sonos API but I can't seem to find it.
In the Sonos app on the "About My System" page when you scroll down (And have a device connected to your tv) it shows "Audio in". I want that information from the API. Is that possible?

Hope to hear,
Kind regards,
Namanix

Answer (score 0):

The Audio In field displays the audio format that Sonos home theater speaker is receiving. See **Check the audio format** in [Troubleshooting low audio from surround speakers](https://support.sonos.com/s/article/3335) for details.

The Sonos platform enables the following line-in APIs and capabilities:

- Use the [loadLineIn](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playback/loadlinein/) command in the `playback` namespace to change the current group source to the line-in source of a specified player.
- View the source type in the `container` object. Sonos home theater products use the `linein.homeTheater` `type`. See `container` in [Playback Objects](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/types/playback-objects/) for details.
- Products with line-in capabilities include the `LINE_IN` `capability` in the `player` object. See the [groups](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/groups/groups/) object for details.

Comment: So the answer is no? I cannot retrieve the value of audio in (stereo 2.0, dolby 5.1, etc..)?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but the **Sonos Play:5 (gen1)** has an UPNP service called [AudioIn](https://svrooij.io/sonos-api-docs/services/audio-in.html).

If my playbar switches to TV mode (I've turned auto switching on), than the CurrentURI changes to `x-sonos-htastream:......`.

Instead of building something yourself, you can also check-out this typescript/node library [@svrooij/sonos](https://svrooij.io/node-sonos-ts).